# retrieve only sub-pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to list all sub-pages only one level though of one particular page. I was reading [Function Reference/get pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages) and thought that `$pages = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $post->ID, 'parent' => $post->ID)) ;` will do the trick but it is not working. It lists all pages on the same level like the page I call that code from. If I omit parent option I will get all pages even with sub-pages that I want. But I want `only` sub-pages.

The whole function is like

```
    function about_menu(){
    if (is_page('about')){

    $pages = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $post->ID, 'parent' => $post->ID)) ;
        foreach($pages as $page)
        {       
        ?>
            <h2><a href="<?php echo get_page_link($page->ID) ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title ?></a></h2>
        <?php
        }   
    }
    }
```

below are screen shots from wp admin and results. Mine is second one

[Screen shot from WP admin http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/6139/e2568e8ec2684e7aa1bb3d1.png](http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/6139/e2568e8ec2684e7aa1bb3d1.png) and [the result http://img269.imageshack.us/img269/2365/329c5097c78f4d3186a177c.png](http://img269.imageshack.us/img269/2365/329c5097c78f4d3186a177c.png)

Comment: what does var_dump($post->ID) throw out?

Comment: @choise: NULL. I thought that would be the reason but I did not know what to do about that....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding

```
global $post;
```

right before you declare $pages.

Comment: @choise: you're genius :-) it did the trick. Could you tell me why it is needed there?

Comment: "the loop" sets up this global variable while looping through this posts. now you can access all objects out of the loop with this variable. (global is for scoping)

Comment: I'm sorry...what `loop` are you talking about?

Comment: so if I want to use any variable from 'the loop' in my code I have to always use the magic word `global`?

Comment: if you want to use some content of the variable "post" (very much information stored in it) outside the loop, you first have to set it global

Comment: gooooood, now I understood. Thank you for that

Answer (score 2):

Check out [`wp_list_pages()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_pages). I think these settings will give you what you want.

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'child_of'     => $post->ID, // current page
    'depth'        => 1, // get children only, not grandchildren
    'echo'         => 1, // print immediately when we call wp_list_pages
    'sort_column'  => 'menu_order', // sort by the menu_order parameter
);      
?>
<?php wp_list_pages( $args ); ?>
```

Comment: can I get the function return array of post ID only? not to print the list of post id or post names?

Comment: Radek, not with that function. There's probably a way to do it.

Comment: thank you. So it looks that I have to use get_pages function. It seems to me that wp_list_pages has easier to use. I like the depth arugument.

Answer (score 0):

```
$paginas = array();
$paginas_obj = get_pages('sort_column=post_parent,menu_order');
$paginas['false'] = "Seleciona pagina";
  foreach ($paginas_obj as $pagina) {
  $paginas[$pagina->ID] = $pagina->post_title;
}
```